# NuxtJs Cannot recall this.$fetch() inside methods

Tags: vue.js, fetch, nuxt.js

I have table filters inside my data which I will be used to reload my table with it, I am using this.$fetch() to do that but just so happen that I cannot recall in from any of my methods

```
<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  async fetch({ store, error }) {
    try {
      await store.dispatch('exams/fetchExams', this.examTableFilter)
    } catch (e) {
      error({
        statusCode: 503,
        message: 'Unable to fetch exams at this time. Please try again.'
      })
    }
  },
  data() {
    return {
      examTableFilter: {
        page: 1,
        length: 10,
        search: '',
        examType: 'ism'
      },
      isModalCrewNewExamActive: false,
      isNew: 1
    }
  },
  computed: mapState({
    exams: (state) => state.exams.exams
  }),
  methods: {
    refresh() {
      this.$fetch()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Any code to share?

Comment: @MichaelGiovanniPumo added code block, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue, and I found the answer.

the problem is that adding params to your fetch declaration breaks it (`fetch({ store, error })`). According to the docs, they shouldn't be there, and you should be pulling them from this.$nuxt.context:

```
const { store, error } = this.$nuxt.context
```

Make these changes, and you'll see it all magically working.